# Visual Studio Code theme issue

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am irritated by this. I tried uninstalling all the themes (I guess), but still the theme does not seem to be working.

How do I fix this?

When the IDE is untouched for few seconds, this comes up like the old screen saver we had in Windows covering up the entire VS Code slowly.

[image: this some sort of theme in VS code]

Comment: this has to do with `graphics hardware enabled`, you can disable it from the command line and maybe with a setting

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be a theme in my opinion. Perhaps, some issue with the display driver.

You can always try reinstalling vscode, just make sure to sync your settings if you've customized vscode .

If the issue persists, you can try changing the graphics settings by selecting display settings from Window's right click context menu -> selecting graphics settings and adding **VScode** to the list by browsing to its exe location, and then select **power saving** to make vscode use the integrated GPU if you're on a laptop.

Comment: Restoring the graphics setting to default worked.